# Why do all enums extend enum<e>

Tags: java, enums

Isn't it impossible to extend a generic type with an undefined type parameter ex:

```
class Foo extends enum<E>
```

How do they extend it?

**edit:** also where is the values() method defined?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you getting the <E> from? `Foo` should be extending `Enum<Foo>`.

Comment: does it implicitly define e when it creates the enum with the type of enum?

Comment: Here is the source for java.lang.Enum, if it helps: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Enum.java.html

Comment: @Thilo: put your comment as an answer. The documentation in the class tells why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed illegal to extend a generic type with an undefined type parameter. However, enums don't do that. If you're decompiling some java code and saw a `<E>` there (And your enum type is not named `E`), your decompiler isn't processing generics properly.

An enum implicitly extends `Enum<YourEnumType>`. That is, implicitly the compiler generates a `class YourEnumType extends Enum<YourEnumType>`. By passing down its own type, it allows `Enum`'s `compareTo` and `valueOf` functions to reject values from different types of `enum`s.

Comment: where is the values() method defined if not in the enum generic?

Comment: @rubixibuc - what isn't artificial in programming? it's syntactic sugar, there's nothing you couldn't write yourself in an enum. but it's more convenient to have the compiler do it for you

Comment: @rubixibuc - that depends on your manner of speaking.  Or to put it another way, without knowing what >>you<< mean by "artificial" we can't answer that.

Comment: I mean it's not predefined in any class but instead by the compiler, what does it return.

Comment: For reference, the implicit declarations are specified in [*§8.9.2. Enum Body Declarations*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2).